# Questions about a basic power supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage, rectifier, rms, bridge-rectifier

What is the difference between the peak voltage and the rms voltage? In our country, the standard voltage in houses is 220V AC. Is it peak or rms?

In the rectifier (I use full-wave bridge rectifier), should I use the rms voltage or the peak voltage in getting the average voltage and for computing the output voltage?

Comment: Come on! Googling for "rms voltage" gives [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) as first link.

Comment: I've been there but I don't really get what every word means. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If unspecified then assume RMS. For a sinewave, the peak voltage is \$\sqrt2\$ higher then the RMS. It's usually reasonable to assume a sinewave.

After a bridge rectifier it is the peak voltage that the capacitor charges up to minus a couple of volt drops due to the diodes in the bridge. You might also consider the ripple voltage due to loading effects discharging the capacitor a little: -

[image]

Notice that the peak voltage of the brown trace doesn't quite reach the peak of the green trace due to the diode volt drop. This can be quite significant because of the duty cycle of the current that charges the capacitor: -

[image]

The charging current that restores the capacitor's peak voltage occurs over a much shorter time period than the full cycle of the AC hence the peak current is quite large. This means that the bridge diodes are pushed quite hard and drop more than the "conventional" 0.7 volts. This peak of current also incurs volt drops in the transformer primary and secondary windings due to copper resistance and leakage inductance.